# server side video trim and join

Tags: php, video-processing

I want to be able to take several mp4 videos on the server, give each start/end time trim points and in the end after trimming join these videos together. There wont be any transitions between videos, all videos are in same format and resolution. Is there a server side php api that could do this job for me?

Comment: Maybe helpful [Check Here](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/3747-PHP-Manipulate-and-convert-videos-with-ffmpeg-program.html)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be what you're looking for. You can definitely trim but it doesn't appear to be able to join, but you might be able to hack something together using the features this toolkit provides. 
https://github.com/buggedcom/phpvideotoolkit-v2

Comment: No idea. I didn't downvote it. I'm assuming it's because a quick Google search sufficed for getting the answer.